# How does the word “en” change meaning and proper ordering?

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots

I came across this sentence:

> J'en suis encore malade…

I was wondering about the structure and usage of *en*. Could the following sentences convey the same meaning? As a beginner, I would tend to say:

> Je suis encore malade…

or

> Je suis encore en malade…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“*Je suis encore malade*” means “I'm still sick”. “*J'en suis encore malade*” means “I'm still sick due to this” or more likely “I'm still feeling uneasy about this” or “I'm still angry about this”. The adverb *en* stands for the reason for the illness or anger. It is always placed before the verb, you can't say “*<s>*je suis encore en malade*</s>”.

Usually, *malade* means sick, ill. However, in some contexts, it can refer not to a sickness but to a general feeling of uneasiness, discontent or even anger. “*J'en suis encore malade*” evokes that alternate meaning by default.

> *On m'a piqué mon vélo la semaine dernière. J'en suis encore malade.*
>   Someone stole my bike last week. I'm still mad about it.

Comment: So I guess the usage in the sentence «J'en suis encore contente» would be in a similar sense?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Grammatically, yes. Semantically, it's weird: *content* is a judgement about a specific action, not a feeling.

Comment: it's interesting, because I thought content = happy (feeling)?

Comment: My semantic issue is that _content_ is too calm a feeling (more satisfaction than happiness) to feeling to disappear, and _encore_ hints just that, that the contentment has to disappear.

Comment: Would this sentence require any correction or would it be okay? «Valérie n'est pas la parce que elle en est encore malade». Merçi

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora *content* means happy in the sense of satisfied about something, it's not a feeling that could be retained or go away. “*Valérie n'est pas la parce que elle en est encore malade*” is correct, but usually you wouldn't use *en*: “Valerie is away because she's still sick”, not “… because she's still sick of it“.

Answer (score 1):

*En* is a pronoun which replaces a complement introduced by *de*.  For instance,

> *J'achète **des fruits**.* <-> *J'**en** achète.*

It can be a complement of a verb (like in the previous example) or in some cases a noun (I think the noun itself must be direct object of the verb or an attribute linked to the subject by a copula verb).

> *Il a peur **des chiens**.* <-> *Il **en** a peur.*
>
> *Je suis malade **d'avoir mangé des fruits pas frais**.* <-> *J'**en** suis malade.*